# Java Version Switch

Tags: java, sdk, version

Can I have ALL the Java versions, from 1 to 21, installed in my computer and simply SWITCH between versions whenever I need to work with a specific version?!

If YES, how can I do it?!

If NO, Thank you!

Haven't tried yet because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Yes you can. You should use the SDK Man software.
```curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash`

Comment: yes you can, i have 4/5 JDK on my system, all "installed" simply unzip the archive of vendor on my ./jdk/ folder. To switch  between version you just have to configure your IDE properly. depends what IDE you are using ! btw Java prior 1.5 (really, 1.8 tbh) is pretty unusable with moder IDE.

Comment: https://sdkman.io/ is your friend.

Comment: You should be using only current version (21 now, 22 later this month) and [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) versions (8, 11, 17, 21). Other versions get no fixes nor security updates (unless perhaps you pay for a support contract).

Comment: shame to windows, is not available for it :(

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes, just download them all and decompress them to different folders. The caveat is that you'll need to add/remove from the path the one you want dynamically, to compile or run code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

You should use the SDK Man software.
`curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash`

When doing the `sdk list java`, you will get a screen like this:

> =============================================================================== Available Java Versions for Linux 64bit
> ================================================================================  Vendor        | Use | Version      | Dist    | Status     | Identifier
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------  Corretto      |     | 21.0.2       | amzn    |            |
> 21.0.2-amzn
> |     | 21.0.1       | amzn    |            | 21.0.1-amzn
> |     | 17.0.10      | amzn    |            | 17.0.10-amzn
> |     | 17.0.9       | amzn    |            | 17.0.9-amzn
> |     | 11.0.22      | amzn    |            | 11.0.22-amzn
> |     | 11.0.21      | amzn    |            | 11.0.21-amzn
> |     | 8.0.402      | amzn    |            | 8.0.402-amzn
> |     | 8.0.392      | amzn    |            | 8.0.392-amzn          Dragonwell    |     | 17.0.9       | albba   |            | 17.0.9-albba
> |     | 11.0.21      | albba   |            | 11.0.21-albba
> |     | 11.0.20      | albba   |            | 11.0.20-albba
> |     | 8.0.402      | albba   |            | 8.0.402-albba
> |     | 8.0.392      | albba   |            | 8.0.392-albba
> |     | 8.0.382      | albba   |            | 8.0.382-albba         Gluon         |     | 22.1.0.1.r17 | gln     |            | 22.1.0.1.r17-gln
> |     | 22.1.0.1.r11 | gln     |            | 22.1.0.1.r11-gln      GraalVM CE    |     | 21.0.2       | graalce |            | 21.0.2-graalce
> |     | 21.0.1       | graalce |            | 21.0.1-graalce
> |     | 17.0.9       | graalce |            | 17.0.9-graalce        GraalVM Oracle| >>> | 21.0.2       | graal   | installed  | 21.0.2-graal
> |     | 21.0.1       | graal   |            | 21.0.1-graal
> |     | 17.0.10      | graal   |            | 17.0.10-graal
> |     | 17.0.9       | graal   |            | 17.0.9-graal

First of all you should install all the different version by:
`sdk install java yourVersion` like `sdk install java 21.0.1-graalce` or `sdk install java 17.0.9-graalce` or `sdk install java 23.ea.12-open`.

This allows you to go to a directory and do `sdk use java 21.0.1-graalce`.

This will activate the JDK 21 version of the GraalVM CommunityEdition (CE).
You can do this for different version in different directories.

Answer (score 0):

For support purposes I have multiple versions of Java installed all the time. Namely, I have:

- Oracle Java 6
- Oracle Java 7
- Oracle Java 8
- Oracle Java 11
- OpenJDK 11
- OpenJDK 17
- OpenJDK 21

Yes, I have two Java 11 from different sources.

You can download the packages separately and decompress them. This stategy avoids using the installers since they will try to manage the system properties and set/reset their own versions as the "default one". You probably want to manage the default manually, not automatically.

Now, your folder will look like:

```bash
jdk1.6.0_34
jdk1.7.0_40
jdk1.8.0_51
openjdk-11+28
java -> jdk-11+28  (this is a symlink)
...
```

The PATH variable includes the symlink folder only. This way I decide which java version to use by switching the `java` symlink -- that is pointing in this example to the OpenJDK 11. If I want to use Java 6, I can repoint the symlink by doing:

```bash
rm java
ln -s jdk1.6.0_34 java
```

Easy, isn't it?

Finally, most IDEs can make this change a lot easier, but I wanted to show you the manual way of doing things, so you can understand there's no magic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

What is your OS? I've used jenv for years and it works very well.

I work with macos, and can install and configure with brew.

https://github.com/jenv/jenv